# Nginx can't redirect HTTPS to WWW

Tags: nginx

I have the Nginx config as below, I'm trying to redirect

```
https://example.com
```

to

```
https://www.example.com
```

But when I enter

```
https://example.com
```

in the browser, I don't see the redirect. Anything idea?

```
server {
   listen 443;
   server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.key;

   return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.key;

    location /media  {
        alias  /media;  # your Django project  media files - amend as required                                                                                         
    }

    location /static {
        alias  /static; # your Django project  static files - amend as required                                                                                        
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
}
```

Comment: The configuration looks fine. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to make sure that Nginx is reading the above configuration. Restart Nginx and clear your browser's cache between configuration changes.

Comment: After I restart everything, testing show it's working now.